# "The specified share does not exist" with file upload to Azure

Tags: azure

I try upload file to my Azure storage:

```
az storage file upload --account-key "KEY" --account-name myaccountname --share-name containername --source .\file.txt
```

and result has error:

```
The specified share does not exist.
RequestId:94d9610c-201a-0032-04cb-a736b8000000
Time:2022-08-04T06:26:04.8341637Z
ErrorCode:ShareNotFound
```

What exactly is "share-name"?
I did think that it is a container name in storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing between Azure Blob Storage and Azure File Storage. If you want to upload to Azure Blob Storage, you would need to use [`az storage blob upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload).

Your command would be something like:

```
az storage blob upload --account-key "KEY" --account-name myaccountname --container-name containername --file .\file.txt
```

Comment: Yes, you have right. Corrected syntax is: "az storage blob upload --account-key "KEY" --account-name myaccountname --container-name containername --file .\file.txt"